# RoR: What would be the best SEO structure, adding a blog feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have migrated a old php/mysql site to ruby on rails, and had to keep the old link structure - not to break incoming links.

**The structure look like this:**
domain.com/artists/user1/seo-friendly-name-of-painting1
domain.com/artists/user1/seo-friendly-name-of-painting2
domain.com/artists/user1/seo-friendly-name-of-painting3
etc.

I thinking about adding a blog to each user-profile. What would be the best structure for adding this new feature? I see two possibilities:

1. Add the blog as a new main item, and link to the user that owns it.
   domain.com/blogs/seo-friendly-name-of-blog-title
2. Add the blog nested under the user:
   domain.com/artists/user1/blogs/seo-friendly-name-of-blog-title

I am worried about mixing the paintings with with the blogs resource - they will be at the same level. Hope I explained it good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both of them work.

With the second solution, you have to enter 2 params -> userid and blog-id/name

I prefer the first one, because you dont have to deal as much with uncorrect data when chaning the get params, like with the second solution. F.e.

```
domain.com/artists/wong user 123123/blogs/seo-friendly-name-of-blog-title
```

would produce another error message like

```
domain.com/artists/user1/blogs/wrong blog title
```

Answer (score 0):

blogs.domain.com/user?...

edit:

if you want to change links structure you can redirect your current links [like this](http://www.seomoz.org/article/guide-to-applying-301-redirects-with-apache)

Comment: I don't know about this suggestion.. it kinda feels wrong to add a subdomain :/

Answer (score 0):

You can also design your URL schema as you like and then setup permanent redirections using mod_rewrite in Apache.  While it may not be the most maintenable approach, I think it may be valuable if it helps you to come up with cleaner routes in your Rails app.

Comment: How would you implement this in my example?